# Save an NSArray as NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

sorry if this is too broad.

I am wondering on how I can turn a json object I've made inside my code (not downloaded from the web) into a saved file? And then, how to read it later, and maybe re-write it with different contents?

What I want to do is to save the highscores of my game to a json array of ints, then save it, and re-read it later. I wanted to use XML for this, but I couldn't find any uptodate tutorial on this. Is this a bad use for JSON? Should I use CoreData instead? Is XML better for this sort of use?

or can you point me to a tutorial on how to do this properly

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to use JSON at all for an internal-only use in objective-c. Surely NSArray or NSDictionary is more suitible (and comes with methods to save to / load from files -- using XML, incidentally).

Comment: +1 for not trying to put this into UserDefaults.

Comment: You can also use nskeyedarchiver. Which effectivly writes your instantiated objects to disk in a binary format.

Comment: @mah I'm a huge noob. I looked at XML stuff for saving, but everyone was praising json so I thought i'd try that instead.

Comment: If the data is consistent with JSON rules (only dictionaries, arrays, NSNumbers, and strings), then it's simple to run it "backwards" through the JSON parser kit of your choice and then write to a file.  Should not require a "cookbook" unless you don't really know how to write Objective-C.

Comment: Conceptually yes; it isn't a good place to store data to transfer it between views. User default are for saving certain types of state between launches - such as user preferences. It becomes to easy to use it as a general Key Value Store, when there are better choices. In fact, if you are trying to save your highscores to a file so that a different view controller can read it, then there are better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you save your scores to an NSArray you can save it to data by using `writeToFile:atomically:` and you can recreate the array by calling `arrayWithContentsOfFile:`

Look them up in the [NSArray reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfFile%3a)

This is easier than turning it into JSON and saving the data.

However; If you are going to be storing more data - Now is a good time to learn about Core Data.

Have a look at the [Core Data Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005316)

Yes, it is a lot to read and learn, but if you start building your foundations early it will help you in the long run.

Comment: Core Data seems like a good idea, but I don't know how to use it. Any good place to start?

Comment: @OscarApeland based on your description of what you're trying to solve, using CoreData instead of what has been suggested is like killing a fly with an atom bomb instead of a fly swatter.

Comment: @mah hahaha, nice metaphor. I get it, but I would want to save other stuff later on aswell.

Comment: @mah For saving an array of integers, maybe. But apps store more than that generally. Also - once you get used to CD, it's trivial to use it to store data such as this. As Core Data is an OS framework - it doesn't bloat the binary.

Comment: @Abizern of course it is, but the question asked was not about the "more than that" storage, it was about something simple enough to represent via JSON... which as you surely know, is nothing that an NSDictionary can't store and that can be saved to/loaded from a file with a single method call for each direction. I'm not saying CD is a bad idea, I'm saying for the problem raised, CD is way overkill. Learning CD for the sake of learning CD is wonderful! Learning it to solve this problem when one isn't aware of the easier methods is not.

Comment: @mah I gave him a simpler method, and told him where to look to go further. I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Abizern sorry -- if I came across as being critical I didn't intend that and I apologize. I agree, CD is the right option for looking towards saving complex data (or performing complex searches on it, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can also save any property-list easily using [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
// Save the array
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.myArray forKey:@"MyArray"];
// Optionally force the save right away
[defaults synchronize];
```

And then:

```
// Load the array
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.myArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"MyArray"];
```

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.